# From Java, how can I access a var defined in a Scala trait?

Tags: java, scala, interop

I have a trait that defines a single var and a single function like what follows:

```
trait MyTrait {
  var myVar: Boolean

  def myFunction = 7
}
```

This trait is used by a class (let's say MyClass) and I'm using that class in a couple of Java files that I haven't converted yet. How, in my existing Java classes, can I access that variable? I can access the method just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out in one last attempt. If you initialize `myVar` it works as expected.

```
var myVar: Boolean = _
```

Comment: though that's doing something slightly different, isn't it? Because it's no longer abstract?

Comment: true. i'm converting a bunch of "hastily" written java classes to scala. a bunch shared common methods so i moved them into a trait so i could compose it. all the classes already inherited something so i coulnd't put it in the existent tree. good enough for now.